# What's wrong in this simple PHP SQL sentence?

Tags: php, sql, mysql, mysql-error-1064

i want to recober all the users with "blo" in their full name, for example: "Pablo"

I pass the "blo" parameter with `user` PHP parameter:

```
$q=mysql_query("select * From user Where fullName Like '%'".$_REQUEST['user']."'%'",$link );
```

something is wrong in the php SQL sentence, because when i try the sentence with the argument "blo" on my SQL database, i see that the SQL sentence is correct, because it returns me correct result, this is the sentence with the argument "blo" on it: `select * From user Where fullName Like "%blo%"`

i'm sure that the PHP is receiven the "blo" parameter correctly, then, it have to be a sintax error of the SQL sentence on the PHP.... but i can't find it

EDIT : OK!! the last sentence is solved, but now i have this new sentence with the same problem, it have a error but i dont know where

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT u.* 
                    FROM USER u
                   WHERE u.fullName LIKE '%%%s%%' AND email NOT IN (select pp.fk_email2 from permission pp where pp.fk_email1='".mysql_escape($_REQUEST['mymail'])."') AND email NOT LIKE  '".mysql_escape($_REQUEST['mymail'])."' ",
                  mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['user']));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL requires single quotes to indicate a string for comparison, and the wildcard character (%) must be included inside of those single quotes.  Double quotes are used for column and table aliasing only, if at all.

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT u.* 
                    FROM USER u
                   WHERE u.fullName LIKE '%%%s%%'",
                  mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['user']));

$q = mysql_query($query, $link);
```

Secondly, you're leaving yourself [open to a SQL injection attack by not sanitizing the user request variable](http://xkcd.com/327/).  Always use mysql_real_escape_string when dealing with strings being submitted to a MySQL database.

Comment: You'll also need to escape the % because of sprintf, so `%%%s%%`

Comment: @Brian: Corrected, thx.  I wasn't sure, don't have PHP handy to test.

Comment: Double quotes can normally be used to specify strings. They are interpreted as table names only is ANSI mode is enabled.

Comment: @AndroidUser99: "it doesn't work" doesn't tell us anything useful - do you get an error? If so, what is it?  Fact is, what I posted *is* valid code so the problem would lie with you altering it somehow...

Comment: are you sure that i have to write %%%s%% and not %%s%% ??? why 3 % in first case and 2 % in second case?

Comment: @AndroidUser99: `%s` is what sprintf uses for the variable replacement placeholder -- that's why there's three `%` on one side, and two on the other.  Checking the sprintf documentation would've been a good place to check before asking...

Comment: oh youre right, thanks a lot!!! it works!!! but now i have another problem, the sentence is now a little more long, and i dont know how to make it working, i have a error similar to the last error, i edited my first post please read it

Answer (score 1):

You have the quotes messed up. use this:

```
$q=mysql_query('SELECT * 
                FROM user
                WHERE fullName LIKE "%' . $_REQUEST['user'] . '%"',$link );
```

BTW, this is bad practice. You are using un-escaped input in your query and are open to SQL injection.

Comment: so, add an escaping function to your answer instead of empty blab on it.

Comment: @Col-shrapnel I would if I had the PHP docs open. since I don't at the moment, and don't remember the function name by heart, I leave it as an exercise to the asker/other asnwers

Comment: @AndroidUser99: "it doesn't work" doesn't tell us anything useful - do you get an error?  If so, what is it?

Comment: no error, it simply doesn't returns nothing, JSON error, it means something is wrong in the PHP SQL sentence

Comment: @AndroidUser99: Stop using JSON, and debug by printing the output to screen.  When that works, *then* progress to looking at JSON...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your quotes are off.. try something like...

```
$q=mysql_query("select * From user Where fullName Like '%".$_REQUEST['user']."%'",$link);
```

Also,  you will want to make sure that the incoming param is sql-escaped to prevent sql injection.  I don't know php, but it's probably something similar to...

```
$q=mysql_query("select * From user Where fullName Like '%".mysql_escape($_REQUEST['user'])."%'",$link);
```

Answer (score 0):

@AndroidUser99: Change the query to --

```
$q = mysql_query("select * from user Where fullName like '%" . $_REQUEST['user'] . "%'", $link);
```

**Update**

I think we may need more code since none of the answers seem to be 'working'. Is the database link even being instantiated in `$link`? If there are errors what are they?

Answer (score 0):

I think it must be ... Where fullname like '%" . $_REQUEST['user']."%'"...
with the % symbol inside the simple quotes.